# I don't know the Encoding code number for German chars

Tags: .net, encoding, character-encoding

Using

```
Encoding sysEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(850)
```

which website lists the code numbers? (Which code number do I use to capture German characters such as the "es zet" and umlauts?)

Comment: No UTF-8 available ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the number you're looking for is: **20106**.

I'm no expert in localization, but three minutes of Googling solved this problem. The msdn documentation on [`Encoding.GetEncoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencoding?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_Encoding_GetEncoding_System_Int32_) says:

> The code page identifier of the preferred encoding. Possible values are listed in the Code Page column of the table that appears in the [Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.8) class topic.

Following that link and scrolling down on that page takes you to the referenced table. There are a couple German-related code pages listed, but the above number seemed to me to be correct.

Comment: The number 20106 results in a ? for the "es zet".